# Random Numbers and probability

Tags: random

How long does a sequence of random decimal digits (0, 1, 2, ..., 9) need to be before you can "reasonably" expect the sequence to contain all numbers from 0 through 999 (inclusive).

--

It's up to you to define "reasonably".

E.g.:
The sequence 1823 contains 1, 2, 3, 8, 18, 23, 82, 182 and 823.

The sequence 1053 contains 0, 1, 3, 5, 10, 53, and 105.

Comment: This is obviously related to the [Coupon Collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem) but the interdependency among sequences makes it not quite the same thing.  (Note that you could just ask for 'all possible three-digit sequences' and have virtually the same problem, but one that might be easier to analyze.)  Interesting question!

Comment: Define what random means for the digits in the sequence. If every natural  number is equally likely to be chosen then there's no hope of finding such a length.

Comment: @Spencer 'Digits' defines that pretty clearly; I think it's natural to assume a uniform distribution that assigns an independent probability $\frac1{10}$ to each digit in the sequence.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, ah I understand now.